# Can't find element using xpath

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

So, here are two divs

```
<div class="th_pr"><input id="user_email" class="accounts_input" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Email" name="user[email]"></input><p class="accounts_error_text" style="display: block;">
  email is invalid
</p></div>
<div class="th_pr"><input id="user_password" class="accounts_input" type="password" size="30" placeholder="Password" name="user[password]" autocomplete="off"></input><p class="accounts_error_text" style="display: block;">
  password can't be blank
</p></div>
```

I need to get those elements with texts "email is invalid" and "password can't be blank" by text, cause it will differ depending on input.

I've been trying to complete this using xpath :

```
By.xpath("//p[contains(.,'email is invalid')]")
```

and

```
By.xpath("//p[contains(.,'password be blank')]")
```

but i get nothing.

```
resultEmail = ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//p[contains(.,'email is invalid')]")).apply(driver);
```

returns true, although the element is visible.

Please help.

Comment: Is it in an IFrame? This commonly trips people up.

Comment: Rather than debugging your xpaths in webdriver, I'd recommend using [firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firepath). It makes the job a lot faster.

Comment: can you please let me know what does driver.findElements(By.class("th_pr")).get(0).getText() returns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xpath

```
//input[@id='user_email']/following-sibling::p
//input[@id='user_password']/following-sibling::p
```

Then you have

```
WebElement emailParagraph = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user_email']/following-sibling::p"));
System.out.println(emailParagraph.getText());
```

Comment: invisibilityOfElementLocated returns boolean, that i need in case of writing if.

Comment: sorry, mistyped. It returns true, actually.

Comment: @user2637419: what would `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(.,'email is invalid')]")).isDisplayed()` give you? and your title says `Can't find element using xpath`, which is a different issue, what's the issue exactly?

Comment: it will give me Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//p[contains(.,'email is invalid')]"}

Comment: and if i wait for it, the wait times out. I think the problem is with xpath. Is there any way to use cssSelector?

Comment: @user2637419 check if the css selector I have mentioned in my answer works for you.

Comment: Ok. This worked. //input[@id='user_email']/following-sibling::p I can find the element. Any suggestions how i can find text inside of it? I need to check the text now.

Comment: @user2637419: Updated again. `emailParagraph.getText()` will get you the text, you can trim the leading/trailing whitespace and compare it with whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `text()` method within the xpath?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'email is invalid')]"));
```

Rather than using the `.`?

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//p[contains(text(), 'email is invalid')]"}

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
WebElement userEmailErrorMessage = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class=\"th_pr\"]:nth-child(1) > p"));

WebElement userPasswordErrorMessage = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class=\"th_pr\"]:nth-child(2) > p"));
```

Using these elements you will be able to read the error messages for the respective input controls.

Comment: Still cannot find it. Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[class=\"th_pr\"]:nth-child(1) > p"}

Comment: The backslashes should not come in there. I have used backslash as an escape character in the locator string.

Comment: I used the same selectors in browser console for the html you have given and I get it right.